# Mathematical notation: x ◁ y

Tags: math, computer-science

I have googled for the meaning of ◁ without avail.

Can anyone explain to me what  x ◁ y means? For example:

z ⊢ x ◁ y

could it mean that we can derive an agreement between x and y from z?

Thanks.

Comment: It will depend heavily on context. Where did you see this notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the Wikipedia [List of Mathematical Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) and it seems that this symbol defines a [normal subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup).